# Pandas - datetimes with timezones - remove timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I spent last several hours tryng to solve a very simple task - write a dataframe to excel which has a column with datetime.

So I have a dataframe and I have a column with datetime:

```
df['date'].iloc[800]
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 5, 9, 10, 8, 280000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 14400))
```

I just want to write it to excel file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("UAEArticles.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        datetime_format='%m/%d%Y',
                        date_format='%m/%d%Y', options = {'remove_timezone': True})

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: Excel does not support datetimes with timezones. Please ensure that datetimes are timezone unaware before writing to Excel.
```

After googling I found dozens of articles, but it seems that everyone is suggesting I need to just remove the timezone. Fine, per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html):

```
df['date'].dt.tz_convert()
```

I still get the error:

```
ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True
```

What shall I do? I don't care about time component at all, I just need days and I need to write it to excel.

Comment: The option `remove_timezone` to XlsxWriter should fix this issue. However, based on your warning message you are using a older version of XlsxWriter that didn't support that option. Update your version of XlsxWriter and it should resolve the issue.